# Ant include file more than once overrides targets

Tags: ant, include, targets

According to the description:

> **How is import different from include?** [...]
>   It is possible to include the same file more than once by using different prefixes, it is not possible to import the same file more than once.

But I couldn't figure out how to do so. I thought it should just work like this:

The includer:

```
<project name="test_includer">
  <include file="testbuild_import.xml" as="A" optional="false"/>
  <include file="testbuild_import.xml" as="B" optional="false"/>
</project>
```

includes:

```
<project name="test_include">
  <target name="target1" description="test target 1">
    <echo>I'm a target</echo>
  </target>

  <target name="target2" description="test target 2">
    <echo>I'm a target too</echo>
  </target> 

  <target name="target3" description="test target 3">
    <echo>I'm a target too</echo>
  </target>

  <target name="target4" description="test target 4">
    <echo>I'm a target too</echo>
  </target>
</project>
```

The output of `ant -projecthelp -buildfile testbuild.xml` looks like:

```
Main targets:
 A.target1  test target 1
 A.target2  test target 2
 A.target3  test target 3
 B.target4  test target 4
Other targets:
```

I do not have any clue why the last one got the B prefix. And with only 3 targets all of them got the A prefix. If I use 9 targets the targets 3,4,5 got an A prefix and the others a B prefix. It seems to me quite random.

I expected to get 8 targets in total, 4 with an A prefix and 4 with an B prefix.

I would be very happy if someone can give me a hint how to do so, or at least explain what happened and why it won't work.

Comment: This looks like a bug in ant, I've opened https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60817

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts @StefanBodewig.